# Definition of the category Sets

Tags: category-theory

In the category Sets consider the object (i.e., set) $A$ defined as the positive real numbers, another object (set) $B$ defined as the negative reals, and a function $f$ defined as the negative square root.  So, $f(25)=-5$ and $f(9)=-3$ , etc.

Now define a functor $F$ from Sets to Sets such that $F(A)=-A$, $F(B)=-B$, and $F(f)=f$.

Strangely, we now we have a "function" that takes the negative square root of a negative number and gives a positive real number.  This is clearly impossible in any normal sense of sets and functions.

As stated in Wikipedia, "the category Set is the category whose objects are Sets.  The arrows or morphisms between sets $A$ and $B$ are all triples $(f,A,B) $ where $f$ is a function from $A$ to $B$."

Here is my problem: The functor above from Sets to Sets shows that f need NOT be a function from one set to another set (because the negative square root function cannot map a negative number to the positive reals).  All this violates the definition of the category Sets, and/or the definition of a function, and/or the definition of a set (of numbers).

What am I doing wrong?  Is $F$ not a functor?  (And if not, how would I be able to tell it's not a valid functor?)

EDIT:  Let me restate the second part of my question (in parentheses above), since it has not been answered so far:  Suppose we have a given category $D$ and we are given a pair of functions (f,g) where the domain of f is the objects of $D$ and the domain of g is the arrows of $D$.  This pair may, or may not, constitute a functor from $D$ to some other (unspecified) category.

My question concerns what methods/tests/procedures one can use to determine whether such a pair of functions constitutes a functor, or not.  (Perhaps no general methods exist, or perhaps the question is too broad, but if that is the case, then that should be the answer to my question.)

Comment: What does $-A$ mean if $A$ is the set of Supreme Court justices?

Comment: @JohnDouma $A$ is the set of real numbers so for $A$ his definition of $F$ is fine, it is tough, only a partial definition. You don't need the rest of the definition of $F$ to see what is wrong here tough (see my answer)

Comment: To define a functor $F\colon Set\to Set$ you must specify for each set $S$ a corresponding set $F(S)$, and then similarly a correspondence on the morphisms. In your 'construction' of $F$ you did not specify a functor at all. Perhaps there lies your confusion.

Comment: Please see detailed Edit and consider reopening.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

$F$ is not a functor. By [definition of a functor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor#Definition), $F(f)$ should be a map from $F(A)$ to $F(B)$ i.e.
$$F(f): F(A) \rightarrow F(B)$$
$f:A\rightarrow B$ cleary doesn't satisfy this as $F(A) = -A \neq A$ and same for $B$, so you cannot have $F(f)=f$ if $F$ is a functor

Comment: I don't think that's a proof that F is not a functor.  I think you've more or less just repeated my "objection" to F.

Comment: @MPitts It certainly is a proof that $F$ is not a functor, because the demand that $F(f)$ should be a map from $F(A)$ to $F(B)$ is part of the definition of a functor. $F$ doesn't satisfy this, so by definition is not a functor. I've editted in a link to this definition

Comment: I disagree.  The definition you cite never says F(.) must be a map between F(A) and F(B).  Furthermore, consider the dual of my example.  In the dual we have f:B-->A which takes negative square roots of negative numbers (in B) to the positive real numbers (in A) - exactly the same operation as F(f):F(A)-->F(B).  Yet that is valid in the dual category, so why is it not  valid here?

Comment: @MPitts Have you read it? I quote: "associates to each morphism $f:X \rightarrow Y$ in $C$ a morphism $F(f): F(X) \rightarrow F(Y) $ in $D$ such that..."

Comment: @MPitts And your example in the dual category doesn't really make any sense. In the dual category of Set, the morfisms are no longer functions

Comment: "Associates" is not the same as "maps."  A map is a function (see Mathstack article 95741).  ''Associates" is more general, and need not be a function (thus the frequent use of that word in category theory). Also, by your argument the dual is not a valid category.

Comment: A possible solution to my problem that I forgot to mention is that maybe the codomain is not the category Sets, but some other category.

Comment: @MPitts yes, $F$ is not a function, since it's domain and codomain aren't sets. However, we are talking about $F(f)$ wich is according to the definition i cited a morfism. The morfisms in Set are functions, so yes, the definition does say that $F(f)$ should be a function and yes, it does say that it should be a function between $F(A)$ and $F(B)$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62041/discussion-between-mpitts-and-jens-renders).

Answer (score -1):

Here is a category D and a functor F that allows the kind of "nonsense" morphisms/functions I was trying to demonstrate in my example.  (Thanks to Jens' comments I can see that Sets was not the right choice for the codomain since that implies morphisms must be functions.)

Let D be a 3 object category with A={25}, B={-5}, and C={-10}. We define f:A$\rightarrow$B where f is the negative square root function.  Also g:B$\rightarrow$C where g(x)=2x.

Now consider the following functor that maps D to its dual: Let the functor F map A to C, B to B, C to A, f to g, and g to f.  This means that in the dual, F(g)=f: -5 $\rightarrow$ 25.  But by definition f is a function that takes the negative square of its argument, so how can f=F(g) take -5 to 25? Obviously this does not make sense in our "normal" way of thinking about functions.

This shows that F(g)=F(A)$\rightarrow$F(B) does not have to be "reasonable" because here we have f=F(g):-5 $\rightarrow$ 25.

Comment: $f$ is not the same thing as $F(f)$, so what's your point?

Comment: @Alex, I've correct typo and clarified text.  Please re-read and re-evaluate.

Comment: The dual category has morphisms that go in the opposite direction. The morphisms $f:A \to B$ and $g:B \to C$ in $D$ are not morphisms in $D^{op}$, so $F(f)=g$,$F(g)=f$ don't make sense if $F$ is to be a functor $D \to D^{op}$. Anyway, the category doesn't "care" what your objects look like or how you call your morphisms, so I still don't understand the issue you're having.

Comment: @Alex, I don't think you're reading my post carefully.  Agreed, f:A-->B does not exist or make sense in the dual.  But the functor maps f to g and A to C and B to B, so we get g:C-->B as desired for the dual category.  Similarly the functor maps g:B-->C to f:B-->A as desired.  (See Math.stackexchange article 2350047 which addresses this exact functor.)

If you don't accept my isomorphic functor between D and its dual, maybe it would be useful to indicate what do you think is the proper isomorphic functor that transforms D to its dual?

Comment: $g$ is already defined: it is a morphism $B \to C$ in $D$. This $g$ is *not* the same thing as the corresponding morphism $C \to B$ in the opposite category. (You might want to call this morphism $g^{op}$.) Maybe you want to say that $F(f) = g^{op}$? Anyway, the duality functor one usually uses maps any object to itself and sends any morphism $f$ to its opposite $f^{op}$. However this is generally not an isomorphism: for instance, the category of sets isn't isomorphic to its dual (think about initial and terminal objects there).

Comment: (1) Yes, your notation captures what I want.  (2)  In the example, D and its dual ARE isomorphic, so obviously there has to a functor between them.  Please see the other math.stack article  #2350047.  (3) Also, I know that in the dual the arrows are turned around, but I don't think it is legal to just turn an arrow around in a functor.  Instead, you have to switch the objects, and leave the arrow alone.  [By definition, the functor must map the morphisms Hom(x,y) to the morphisms Hom(F(x),F(y)). It does not map Hom(x,y) to Hom(F(y),F(x)). So the functor cannot just turn the arrow around.]

Comment: Yes, it is true that the functor that switches around $A$ and $C$ and sends $f \mapsto g^{op}$, $g \mapsto f^{op}$ is an isomorphism from $D$ to its opposite. As for the duality functor I mentioned, I should have said that it is a *contravariant* functor: it maps $\operatorname{Hom}(x,y)$ to $\operatorname{Hom}(F(y),F(x)) = \operatorname{Hom}(y,x)$. Thought of as a honest covariant functor $D \to D$ or $D^{op} \to D^{op}$, it is just the identity.